# PrimeFaces.monitorDownload complete method is never triggered

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem related to the monitorDownload functionality, more specifically, it seems that the complete method is never triggered and as a result, the entire page is blocked.
I have a commandButton that once pressed, triggers the download:

```
<p:commandButton id="commandButtonCI"
                 value="#{labels['target_checkout']}"
                 actionListener="#{contentBean.checkOut()}" ajax="false"
                 onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, updatemapcourse, 'mapCourse')"
                 styleClass="size_button">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{contentBean.file}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

The start function calls:

```
PF('uiBlocker').show();
```

which blocks the screen, while the complete function (updatemapcourse) is a remoteCommand, but I never reach this point. Initially, I thought that the monitorDownload is not creating the 'primefaces.download' cookie after the checkOut() method is executed, but I can see it in the Cookies section of Chrome DevTools. The problem is that the cookie is always marked as httpOnly (I tried to create a custom cookie, similar to 'primefaces.download', mark it as httpOnly = false, but it is always set to httpOnly = true). From what I understood, JS cannot read httpOnly cookies and that is the reason the monitorDownload never calls the complete method. I tried to implement a custom monitorDownload without using cookies:

```
PrimeFaces.monitorDownload = function(start, complete, monitorKey) {
if(this.cookiesEnabled()) {
    if(start) {
        start();
    }

    window.downloadMonitor = setInterval(function() {
        var downloadComplete = false;
        if(monitorKey == 'mapCourse') {
            downloadComplete = document.getElementById("targetTableauxTab:mapcourseForm:mapCourseDownloadFlag").value;
        } 

        if(downloadComplete === true) {
            if(complete) {
                complete();
            }
            clearInterval(window.downloadMonitor);
            downloadComplete = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

}

Instead of cookies, I thought that I could use an hiddenInput that would be updated by the checkOut() method:

```
<h:inputHidden id="mapCourseDownloadFlag" value="#{contentBean.primefacesDownloadFlag}"/>
```

The problem that I now have is that the hidden input is never updated with the value set in checkOut() because of the ajax="false". I also cannot use oncomplete or onsuccess events because of this. Unfortunately, I don't have any other ideas on how to handle this error. I thought that maybe someone from here had the same problem and found a workaround.

The Primefaces version I use is 8.0.3.

Comment: If you upgrade PF to at least 10, you can use Ajax downloading.

Comment: From what I see here: [link](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml?jfwid=4fafa) , if I use Ajax Downloading, I cannot block the screen while the contents of the file are processed. My file is pretty large and it takes like 5 minutes to finish. I need to block the screen so that the user doesn't leave the page.

Comment: + the project is pretty big. If I change the version to PF10, maybe there is a chance that I can break something else.